# CSS nth-child only applies for n=1

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style the children of #past such that the most recent is completely opaque and those proceeding it fade to transparent. Only the first rule (for nth-child(1)) is being applied (and to *all* children).

The CSS:

```
#past:nth-child(1){opacity:0.55;}
#past:nth-child(2){opacity:0.60;}
#past:nth-child(3){opacity:0.65;}
#past:nth-child(4){opacity:0.70;}
#past:nth-child(5){opacity:0.75;}
#past:nth-child(6){opacity:0.80;}
#past:nth-child(7){opacity:0.85;}
#past:nth-child(8){opacity:0.90;}
#past:nth-child(9){opacity:0.95;}
#past:nth-child(10){opacity:1.00;}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="past">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrngytjj/

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If none of the answers work or you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not work to specify the container. You need to specify the child type

```css
#past div:nth-child(1){opacity:0.55;}
#past div:nth-child(2){opacity:0.60;}
#past div:nth-child(3){opacity:0.65;}
#past div:nth-child(4){opacity:0.70;}
#past div:nth-child(5){opacity:0.75;}
#past div:nth-child(6){opacity:0.80;}
#past div:nth-child(7){opacity:0.85;}
#past div:nth-child(8){opacity:0.90;}
#past div:nth-child(9){opacity:0.95;}
#past div:nth-child(10){opacity:1.00;}
```

```html
<div id="past">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like a revenge down vote. I see no reason for down voting this.

Comment: @ManojKumar, thats what Im thinking! So petty!

Answer (score 2):

When you say `#past:nth=child(1)` you're saying take the first existence of `#past` and apply the css opacity. you need to target the `divs` inside `#past` to get the effect you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrngytjj/2/

```
#past div:nth-child(1) {opacity:0.55;}
#past div:nth-child(2) {opacity:0.60;}
#past div:nth-child(3) {opacity:0.65;}
#past div:nth-child(4) {opacity:0.70;}
#past div:nth-child(5) {opacity:0.75;}
#past div:nth-child(6) {opacity:0.80;}
#past div:nth-child(7) {opacity:0.85;}
#past div:nth-child(8) {opacity:0.90;}
#past div:nth-child(9) {opacity:0.95;}
#past div:nth-child(10){opacity:1.00;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `nth-child` will look for parent element to determine the number of which it should affect the element.

In your code, the parent for `#past` is `body`, therefore it targets all the elements inside it to have the opacity. Instead you should target the child element `div`.

```css
#past div:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 0.55;
}
#past div:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0.60;
}
#past div:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0.65;
}
#past div:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0.70;
}
#past div:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
#past div:nth-child(6) {
  opacity: 0.80;
}
#past div:nth-child(7) {
  opacity: 0.85;
}
#past div:nth-child(8) {
  opacity: 0.90;
}
#past div:nth-child(9) {
  opacity: 0.95;
}
#past div:nth-child(10) {
  opacity: 1.00;
}
```

```html
<div id="past">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, revenge for your comment :)